# Harmon.ie addon keeps disappearing

Tags: outlook-addin, harmon.ie

Outlook 2016. For some reason, my harmon.ie add-on in Outlook keeps disappearing. I have to keep loading it from File - Options - Add-on and check off harmon.ie

Check mark keeps disappearing every time I re-open Outlook - why?

Windows 7 64bit with Office 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few configuration options that may impact plugin availability:
•   File -> Slow and Disabled plugins
•   Double check if harmon.ie listed here – if so, select ‘Always load this plugin’.
•   File -> Options -> Addins -> Manage Disabled Items
•   If harmon.ie is listed, remove it from disabled item lists and re-enable via ‘Manage COM Addins’.
•   Check value LoadBehavior=3 under [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook.Sidebar.AddInShim]
•   If LoadBehavior is set to different value than 3 - set the value to 3 and restart Outlook.
•   Also double check LoadBehavior value under [HKLM\Software[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook.Sidebar.AddInShim] – the value there must be set to LoadBehavior=3. -You may also confirm whether harmon.ie add-in works OK when no other add-ins are enabled- temporarily disable all other add-ins via Tools -> Options -> Add-ins -> Manage COM Addins
•   Uninstall harmon.ie and check whether harmon.ie is still listed in Outlook under 'Inactive addins'. If so - use'Remove' button in Outlook under File -> Options -> Addins -> Manage COM Addins to delete harmon.ie registration and re-installed harmon.ie.

Thanks,

----- Jean